# Exclude data based on cell value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to exclude specific items from my pymysql query:

```
results = """SELECT t.id, s.name
             FROM database.table as t
             LEFT JOIN (database.secondtable as s)
             ON (t.id = s.person_id)
             WHERE s.name != 'John';"""
db_conn pymysql.connect(host='xx', user='xx')
df = pd.read_sql(data, con=db_conn)
```

The sql code works within my mysql serve to exclude any people who have the name John, but when I run it as the above in Python then people with the name John aren't excluded. How do I correct this within Python?

Comment: if =! valid for mysql? The docs refer to != and <>

Comment: I meant to type !=. I have also check this using <> and it doesn't work but does work within the mysql server. Edited the top to show it the correct way around.

Comment: You also don't reference "results" in your read_sql call. I'm not an expert in pandas, but are you allowed to use a pymysql connection? The docs talk about using an SQLAlchemy connection